# linux/ubuntu awk match unique values (instead of bash "sort unique grep" unique values)

Tags: awk, grep

My command looks like this:

> cut -f 1 dummy_FILE | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}' | for i in $(cat -); do grep -w $i dummy_FILE |
>   awk -v VAR="$i" '{distance+=$3-$2} END {print VAR, distance}'; done

```
cat dummy_FILE
Red   13    14
Red   39    46
Blue   45    23
Blue   34    27
Green   31    73
```

I want to:
For every word in $1 dummy_FILE (Red, Blue, Green) - Calculate sum of differences between $3 and $2.

To get the output like this:

```
Red 8  
Blue -29  
Green 42
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to replace `cut -f 1 dummy_FILE | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}'`?
   I am using `sort | uniq -c` to extract every word from the dataset - is it possible to do it with awk?
2. How can I overcome useless `cat` in `for i in $(cat -)`?
3. `grep -w $i dummy_FILE` works fine, but I want to replace it with awk (should I?); If so how can I do this?
   When I am trying to `awk -v VAR="$i" '/^VAR/ '{distance+=$3-$2} END {print VAR, distance}'` I am getting `"fatal: division by zero attempted"`.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do here? What do you mean by 'simple' math? Also, you'll get better answers if you list some sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ a[$1]=a[$1] + $3 - $2 } END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' dummy
```

Results:

```
Red 8
Blue -29
Green 42
```

If you require sorted output, you could simply pipe into `sort` like arutaku suggests:

```
awk '{ a[$1]=a[$1] + $3 - $2 } END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' dummy | sort
```

You can however, print into `sort` (within the `awk` statement), like this:

```
awk '{ a[$1]=a[$1] + $3 - $2 } END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] | "sort" }' dummy
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it using:

```
awk '{a[$1] = a[$1] + $3 - $2;} END{for (x in a) {print x" "a[x];}}' dummy_FILE
```

Output:

```
Blue -29
Green 42
Red 8
```

If you want to sort the output, just append `sort` after the `AWK` command.